# Open all documentations/help pages in a single window

Tags: documentation, windows

**1**

Anyone else face this issue of Left and Right sides clipped in the Documentation center? At 100%, 75% and 50% as below
[image: 0]

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

**2**

How can I set the documentations/help_pages to open in the same *Wolfram Language Documentation Center* window rather than popping many individual help windows that get stacked on top of each other.

Comment: For reference, could you mention the size of your monitor?

Comment: 1920 x 1080 - Dell P2317H 60Hz 8-bit

Comment: 1. No haven't seen that 2. If you use the F1 shortcut to look up symbols, or click the >> in usage messages, then no new help window will open. The existing one will be reused. The only way I can open a new help window is to invoke the menu item Help -> Wolfram Documentation.

Comment: 1. Contact WRI Support 2. By default they use the same window unless you press Shift. So looks like the case for support as well. Maybe this can help: http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12464

Comment: @kuba I shall do that, I am not sure if it's cos of dual monitors though. Either way I will let the support know.

Comment: On my system (windows 10 laptop + dell 1920x1200 + v10 student), a new documentation window always opens when click on anything in the table of contents (for example, Machine Learning => Neural Networks). Quite annoying. Doesn't happen when I click on anything other link or do F1.